# Find the parent tag of the most occurring tag - BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

While working on a scraper with BeautifulSoup, I ran into a problem where I needed to find the parent tag of the most occuring `<p>` tag on a page. For Example:

```
<div class="cls1">
   <p>
   <p>
   <p>
</div>
<div class="cls2">
   <p>
   <P>
</div>
```

I need to get the the tag which has the most direct children that are `<p>` elements. In the above example, it would be `<div class="cls1">` since there are 3 `p` tags as opposed to `.cls2` which only contain 2.

Any suggestions on how I would approach this or if this is entirely possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `max()` built-in function with custom `key=`:

```
data = '''<div class="cls1">
   <p>
   <p>
   <p>
</div>
<div class="cls2">
   <p>
   <P>
</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')

print(max(soup.select('div:has(> p)'), key=lambda k: len(k.findChildren('p', recursive=False))))
```

Prints:

```
<div class="cls1">
   <p>
   </p><p>
   </p><p>
</p></div>
```

Comment: Elegant Solution. Thank You! @Andrej

Comment: This solution is very interesting.  It works most of the time when I'm trying to scrape a news site. I'm currently trying to develop a generic text parser for news sites.  Does any of your 2,518 answers on  `BeautifulSoup` address this topic?  Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: I'm asking this question, because your solutions doesn't work for these web links: https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2023/03/26/business/corporate-business/toshiba-future  or  https://www.kyivpost.com/post/14966

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex Every site is different, there isn't "one solution for them all". For example japantimes uses javascript to load the content. The kyivpost has `<section>` instaod of `<div>`. etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Yes, I know that some sites used javascript, which might require me to use `selenium`.  And yes the kyivpost uses <section> instead of <div>.  I was trying to modify your max to cover both <div> and <section>.  I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, because it was so elegant.  I was able to use your example to build something that works for most of the sites that I want to scrape.  Thanks.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex You can for example do `soup.select('div:has(> p), section:has(> p)')`